# mosbatch command requires a newline on stdin

Tags: mosix

In the newest version of [MOSIX](http://www.mosix.cs.huji.ac.il/txt_distributions.html) (3.14.0.12), all mosix commands which launch on a remote node (`mosbatch` and `mosrun -M`) do not quit until I tap the *return key*. The command properly executes on the remote node, disappears from the remote node process list, but nothing happens until I tap that return key.

For commands which do not read from STDIN themselves, the following works:

> echo | mosrun -M -3 echo bla

Needless to say, this is very annoying. And of course, the above only applies to commands that do not read STDIN. My mosix cluster becomes completely unusable. Where could I start to look for the solution to this issue?

Corrolary: Are there other locations I would be better off posting this question? Newsgroups/mailing lists?

Comment: Just to double check, are you on MOSIX or openMOSIX?

Comment: One more thing you could always follow the command with ampersand `&` to have it run in the background.

Comment: This is on Mosix, _not_ on OpenMosix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only correct answer here seems to be:

Mosix is not used in public clusters anymore. Currently, it is only used at the Hebrew University of Jerusalem. The publication history on Mosix suggest this: all papers published on the system originated from the University of Jerusalem.
The OpenMosix project, a fork from late 2001, is also dead as of March 1st 2008 [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMosix)

No public forums on Mosix exist. The HPC community moved on to using job scheduling systems like SLURM, SGE or TORQUE.

Currently, it is best to move away from Mosix. A lot of universities already did (e.g. Uppsala university replaced Mosix with SLURM).

Comment: I'm sorry, hope the transition goes fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just wrap that into a bash or zsh function to make it quicker to type, not an exact answer but I figured it could be helpful:

```
qmosrun() { echo | mosrun $@ echo bla }
```

(qmosrun for quick mosrun).

EDIT: Oh and if you've got any questions you could try checking out the openMOSIX IRC channel,  on irc.freenode.net on #openMosix . I'm not sure whether you're on mosix or openmosix but it's likely a good place to find some people to talk to regardless http://tldp.org/HOWTO/openMosix-HOWTO/x1840.html

Comment: #openMosix is completely deserted, no other 'mosix' channels exist on Freenode IRC when doing `/msg Alis LIST *mosix*`

Comment: ahhh, yeah, sorry I read that openmosix shut down, sorry. I've tried looking around for you and checking a bunch of docs (I'd be happy to post them if you want) but I haven't been able to find anything else, sorry. My only suggestions are reaching out to the makers of mosix or customising your environment to stop this being such a problem.

Comment: I reached out to the makers of mosix on mosix@mosix.org, but I got no reaction. No other forums seem to exist for Mosix. It is probably safe to assume that the regular kernel updates posted are only for internal use at Hebrew University of Jerusalem, and nobody else really uses Mosix anymore.